# A simple question regarding conditional statements and defining variables

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering 
1. why the console is throwing out a specific result
2. how to get the console to throw out the result I want based on the code

I've tried both removing the else condition and adding it, but I'm stuck because I don't know what the code is thinking.

```
isMarried = false; 
if (isMarried = false) {
    isMarried = 'Nope, not at all! ';
} 

console.log(firstName + ' is a ' + age + ' year old ' + job + '. Is he married? ' +isMarried );


//This outputs false for isMarried instead of "Nope, not at all!" 

If I add an else like so: 
 if (isMarried = false) {
    isMarried = 'Nope, not at all! ';
} else {
    isMarried = 'Oh yeah';
}

//The same code outputs "Oh yeah." I'm a bit confused why it's happening like this. Any thoughts?
```

Basically, I expected the computer to see isMarried as a false boolean, and if this is the case, I wanted to set the variable to the string seen above. Otherwise, if I changed it to true, for example, the it would be a different string.

Comment: `=` and `===`  are two different things, you need to use `comparison operator` instead of `assignment operator` in `if ()`

Comment: in this particular situation you may use `if (!isMarried) { ... } `

Comment: `if (isMarried = false)` --- this always executes the `else` branch, if one exists. `isMarried = false` is an assignment and the value of the entire expression is the value of the right-hand side value (`false` in this case). Read about the [loose equality comparison operator (`==`) and strict equality comparison operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use assignment operators (=) inside conditionals. Inside conditionals, you need to use comparison operators (==, !=, >=, <, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value to your `isMarried`(`false`) inside the IF statement .. you need to use compare operators like `==`

```
a == b // this operator will return a `Boolean` value (`true` Or `false`)
a = b  // this operator will return the value of `b` (right value)
```

So  :

```
isMarried = false  // this will return the right value (false) which means the IF statement
                   // won't work and the else code will be auto executed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Give me green tick if this code satisfied ya..

```
    var isMarried = false;
    if(isMarried==false){
    isMarried = "Not at all";
    }else{
    isMarried = "Oh yeah";
    }

    console.log(isMarried)
```